# How to perform a queryset in Django with a loop for in

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

i use a queryset to obtain a user list from a city:

```
usuarios = Usuario.objects.filter(municipio=muni).exclude(user_id = ide)
```

so i get something like:

[Usuario: user1, Usuario: user2, Usuario: user3]

that is good but i need to do another queryset for obtain their devices

```
for usuario in usuarios:
    devices = GCMDevice.objects.filter(user_id=usuario.user.id)
```

and i get only the last device from the last user(usuario):

[GCMDevice: samsung]

anybody know how can i obtain all devices from that users?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is more options.
Put it into a dictionary with the user's id as a key:

```
for usuario in usuarios:
    devices[usario.user.id] = GCMDevice.objects.filter(user_id=usuario.user.id)
```

but this is a bit demanding for the DB, as it is doing too many queries. So you can obtain all the `DCMDevice` records via a single query:

```
user_ids = Usuario.objects.filter(municipio=muni).exclude(user_id=ide).values_list('user_id', flat=True)
devices = GCMDevice.objects.filter(user_id__in=user_ids)
```